# How to get autocompletion data in chrome developer console by javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

Hello.

I want to get all of auto-completion data like above picture by javascript.

For example,

```
console.log(data) // data is auto-completion data  

["a[0]", "__defineGetter__", "__defineSetter__", ...] // result of above command
```

Any ideas to get autocompletion data?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe: `Object.keys(a)` or a for each loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want all the properties (even non enumerated) of the object as well as any that are present up the prototype chain (e.g. using `__proto__`). E.g. :

```
a = new Array(10); 
a[0] = 1;
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a).concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a.__proto__)).concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a.__proto__.__proto__)));
```

Will print:

```
["0", "length", "length", "constructor", "toString", "toLocaleString", "join", "pop", "push", "concat", "reverse", "shift", "unshift", "slice", "splice", "sort", "filter", "forEach", "some", "every", "map", "indexOf", "lastIndexOf", "reduce", "reduceRight", "entries", "keys", "copyWithin", "find", "findIndex", "fill", "constructor", "toString", "toLocaleString", "valueOf", "hasOwnProperty", "isPrototypeOf", "propertyIsEnumerable", "__defineGetter__", "__lookupGetter__", "__defineSetter__", "__lookupSetter__", "__proto__"]
```

Comment: I really appreciate for your help. :)